# Stuck on making a dummy variable in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy variable if two column criteria are met but its not working. So for example, in my data I want the dummy variable to be 1 if the firm_state is CA, MA, MD, ME...etc and my State is CA, MA, MD, ME, etc.. So in my picture I would want the lines that have the State as MD or ME and the firm_state as CA to have dummy variable "1" and the others that have State as AZ or TX and firm_state as CA to have "0". However, when I write my code, I just have everything in same_party as having a dummy variable "1". Can someone please tell me where I went wrong? This is my current code.

```
data <- data %>%
mutate(same_party = ifelse(firm_state == "CA" | firm_state == "CO" | 
firm_state == "NY" & State == "MD" | 
State == "ME" | State == "WA", 1, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you are able to provide us with a sample of your data. For instance, you could type `dput(data)` and paste the output in your post.

Comment: Like @Matt said, it's really hard to help when you're example isn't reproducible. That said, I think you could solve this with some parentheses in your `ifelse()` statement, bracketing the different combinations you're after. You might also check out `case_when()` from `dplyr` as a way to make your syntax clearer and thus easier to debug.

Comment: yes I think your logic is including pretty much everything because you aren't using parenthesis in your ifelse

Comment: My apologies. I can see how my picture can be a little confusing. My data consists of thousands of lines of data from the same "firm_state" so I wasn't sure of how to display it. I probably should have made a separate example. But DPH was able to answer my question. Thank you for the help anyway!

Comment: If you found the answers to be helpful, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your conditions are not well separated or grouped. Meaning that you have chain of "or" with one "and" in the middle. Using to pais of brackets should solve your problem:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(same_party = ifelse((firm_state == "CA" | firm_state == "CO" | 
                               firm_state == "NY") & (State == "MD" | 
                               State == "ME" | State == "WA"), 1, 0))
```

A bit more comprehensible would be the use of the %in% operator:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(same_party = ifelse(firm_state %in% c("CA","CO","NY") & State %in% c("MD","ME","WA"), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My data finally looks right. I didn't think of adding the extra brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%` instead of lots of `==`:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(same_party = ifelse(firm_state %in% c("CA","CO","NY") &
                             State %in% c("MD","ME","WA"),1,0))
```

Dummy data:

```
data = data.frame(
  State = sample(c("AZ","LA","MD","ME","MD","WA"),10, TRUE),
  firm_state = sample(c("CA","CO","NY"), 10, TRUE))
```

Output:

```
   State firm_state same_party
1     WA         CA          1
2     MD         CO          1
3     MD         CA          1
4     LA         CA          0
5     MD         NY          1
6     ME         NY          1
7     MD         NY          1
8     MD         NY          1
9     LA         NY          0
10    ME         NY          1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have to learn more about the %in% function